# Callback isolated from component's properties

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, typescript

I am new with TypeScript and Angular 2.

I have a strange problem with Cordova Camera Plugin : when I take a photo, it seems callbacks are isolated from the rest of the component !

Here the code :

**result.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-result',
    templateUrl: 'result.component.html'
})
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {
    pictureSource;
    destinationType;
    status = 0; //VALUE I WANT TO PRINT

    constructor() {
        this.pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        this.destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    test() {
        console.log(this.status); //VALUE I PRINT
    }

    capturePicture() {
        let cameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: this.destinationType.FILE_URI
        };
        navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onCaptureSuccess, this.onCaptureFail, cameraOptions);
    }

    onCaptureSuccess(fileURI: string): void {
        console.log(this.status); //THROW ERROR
    }

    onCaptureFail(error: string): void {
        console.log('error', error);
    }
}
```

**result.component.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>Photo</h1>

    <button (click)="capturePicture()">PHOTO</button>
    <button (click)="test()">TEST</button>
</div>
```

**Console output :**
[image: Console output]

When I click on `TEST button` (8 times in this screenshot), I've got console.log whose works.
Then, when I click on `PHOTO button`, take the picture, and come back, I've got `Cannot read property 'status' of null` 
Then, I click 4 times on `TEST button` and status value appears....

It seems `navigator.camera.getPicture`'s callbacks are isolated from the rest of the component, how can we explain that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Angular or Cordova, but it looks like a simple loss of *this* context. The click handler from Angular does respect the components context. But in the line...

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onCaptureSuccess, this.onCaptureFail, cameraOptions);
```

...you just hand over a reference to a function and *getPicture* cannot know your context. One way to solve this, is to bind on *this*:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onCaptureSuccess.bind(this), this.onCaptureFail, cameraOptions);
```

Or use an arrow function, or buffer *this* yourself with a closure, or...

Comment: It was indeed a loss of this context. I didn't thought it could come from here, thank you !